# beforeunload() event to be triggered only when window/tab closed but not on any other condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our specific use case requires that we alert the user only when they're trying to close a window or tab in a browser, but not on other triggers of this event such as clicking on an href _blank for urls that open in new window. Is this possible with raw JS either via this event handler or some other? Thanks

Comment: There is no way to know what really causes the unload. Plenty of dupes out there on this.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello will close this one.